# Android 4.1.x streaming rtsp

Tags: java, android, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp

I have a ip camera that with rtsp link, i went to play this stream an android devices locally and remotely. With android 4.0.x (galaxy tab 10) it works fine but with android 4.1.x (galaxy note II) it works only in local. 
This is my class

```
public class Test extends Activity {   

VideoView vw;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.class_videosurf);
    vw = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    //local works fine with all android versions
    //SrcPath = "rtsp://192.168.1.10/nphMpeg4/g726-640x480";
    //remote works only with android 4.0.x
    SrcPath = "rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx/nphMpeg4/g726-640x480";
    vw.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
    vw.requestFocus();
    vw.start();

}
}
```

Comment: Are you able to access the remote host on the same phone via browser?

Comment: I have had several problems with rtsp, at last it was my internet firewall that blocked all needed ports (TCP: mostly 554 used, UDP: 6899-6900). have a look at the firewall configurations - Android isnt blocking ports with a builtin firewall;)

Comment: the same rtsp link works fine with other devices so i dont think that this is due to my computer firewall

Comment: No, it's only "cannot play this video" !!